# Unable to transform value for property path "fechaReclamacion": datefmt_format: string '' is not numeric

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

```
ERROR: Unable to transform value for property path "fechaReclamacion": datefmt_format: string '' is not numeric, which would be required for it to be a valid date
```

I am a object with a DateTime, in my form i have the next:

```
->add('fechaReclamacion','birthday',array(
            'input' => 'datetime',
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'DD-MM-YYYY',
                'class' => 'datepicker')
        ))
```

Entity:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="fechaReclamacion", type="datetime")
 */
protected $fechaReclamacion;
```

When it try render the form i get the error. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

This mean the field can't be empty.

What you can do:

1. add a `NotBlank` Validator constraint on the entity field
2. add a default value in the entity constructor, eg `$this->fechaReclamacion = new \DateTime('1970-01-01');`
3. add a frontend validation by making the form field required with the `'required' => true` option

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you forgot to add the fields to the database with
`php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`  (or `--force`).

Another think : Look if the database field does not contains a value like '00-00-000'.